# Bad performance of MobileVLCKit?

Tags: objective-c, vlc, libvlc

I have i problem. I builded MobileVLCKit and use in my project. All works, but video playing has bad performance (lagging). Where is the problem? Console says only:

```
creating player instance using shared library
shader program 1: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'TexCoord1' not read by fragment shader
WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'TexCoord2' not read by fragment shader
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please give information about the OS target and the VLCKit version you are using.

Comment: tvOS 9.0 and MobileVLCKit (compiled for Apple TV)